# Taking inputs in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Recently I started studying about Python and I have come across one problem. 
Suppose you are given 3 space separated integers, say 4 5 6
When I use input() method and take the input, it is showing me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P_Try.py", line 1, in <module>
    x= input();
  File "<string>", line 1
    4 5 6 
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess, since it is in one line, it is assuming it to be a string, but finds out the integer at the location 2 (index starting from 0).
I tried alternative method that I took the input as a string using raw_input() method and and wherever I find a number, I cast it as int and append it to the list.

Is there any better way of accomplishing the task?

Answer (score 5):

Function `input()` is interpreting your input as a Python code, I know, it's little odd. To get raw input (string containing user typed characters), just use `raw_input()` function instead.

Comment: Just to add to this answer. If you use Python 3, you can simply use input. If you are starting off, you should probably start using Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input()`, python tries to interpret the input, therefore getting confused when it finds a space.

You correctly suggested using `raw_input()`.

```
inp = raw_input() # get raw input
lst = inp.split(" ") # split into list
num_lst = map(int, lst) # apply int() to all items
```

Comment: you can just use `inp.split()` and it will automatically do it for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just started studying then use python3. `input` line of your code would work fine.
If you need to input 3 integers, you can use code like this:

```
x = input()
result = [ int(i) for i in x.split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a = []
a += map(int,raw_input("Enter the integers\n").split(" "))
print a
```